# How to get the message status read/unread using XMPP Smack API?

Tags: android, sockets, xmpp

I am using smack api for android chat application. I have implemented text message and image sending successfully. But I am not getting the way how can I get the message status either it is read by end user or not? Please give me some example link or provide me a code snippet so that I can do this.

Currently I am using following code to send message.

```
Message msg = new Message(to, Message.Type.chat);
                Log.d("=====SEND MSG====>>", msgText);
                msg.setBody(msgText);
                connection.sendPacket(msg);
```

Thanks in advance.